# Crear documento word en Java con Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-word

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JAVA que pasa textos que contienen etiquetas html a formato word.
Estoy usando la librería Apache POI y todo me funciona correctamente hasta que a un párrafo le intento poner un color de texto, y me da el siguiente error:

> run.setColor("#0000FF"); = >There is no method "setColor" in class "org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun"<

A continuación os pongo el código de mi función:

```
 //Blank Document
 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); 
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( file);
 org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(sentencia.getContenidoSentencia());
 // Selecciona todos los párrafos usando la etiqueta "p"
 Elements parrafos = doc.select("p");
 // Itera a través de los párrafos
 for (Element parrafo : parrafos) 
 {
      // Crear un nuevo párrafo en el documento Word
      XWPFParagraph wordParrafo = document.createParagraph();

      // Busca elementos span con estilo color: blue dentro del párrafo
      Elements elementosAzules = parrafo.select("span[style*=color:blue]");

      // Itera a través de los elementos azules
      for (Element elementoAzul : elementosAzules) 
      {
           // Obtiene el texto del elemento azul
           String textoAzul = elementoAzul.text();

           // Crea una nueva corrida (run) en el párrafo de Word
           run = wordParrafo.createRun();
                             
           // Aplica el formato de color azul al texto
           //LINEA QUE DA ERROR
           //LINEA QUE DA ERROR
run.setColor("#0000FF"); // Código de color azul
           //FIN LINEA QUE DA ERROR
           //FIN LINEA QUE DA ERROR
           run.setText(textoAzul);
      }

      // Agrega el resto del texto del párrafo (fuera de los elementos azules) al párrafo de Word
      String textoFueraAzul = parrafo.text().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
      if (!textoFueraAzul.isEmpty()) 
      {
           wordParrafo.createRun().setText(textoFueraAzul);
      }
 }
                    
 paragraph = document.createParagraph();
 run = paragraph.createRun();
 run.setText("");
 document.write(out);
 out.close();
```

He seguido las instrucciones que se dan en esta página https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm

En primera instancia he probado con la version POI 3.9 porque es la que hasta este momento estaba usando en mi proyecto, pero también he probado con la que pone el enlace anterior (5.1).

Utilizo el IDE Netbeans 8.2 y Java 8.

Comment: Pues da la impresión de que no estás refrescando bien las dependencias. De acuerdo con el javadoc, la versión 5.0.x tiene ese método (en el ejemplo la cadena aparece sin la almohadilla, por cierto). Mientras que en 3.17 ni siquiera existe esa clase y me ha parecido que los métodos para establecer el color reciben un argumento de la clase Color.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado el problema. El codigo anterior es todo correcto, el problema venia de que en una libreria antigua estaba usando una version todavia mas antigua de apache Poi, la version 3.7) que no contenia el metodo setColor("color").